# How to send SMS automatically in Flutter & Kotlin in foreground state, background state and terminated state

Tags: flutter, kotlin, sms, background-process

I am receiving and sending message through Telephony. It is working perfectly when the app is in foreground state but it is not working when the app is in background, though my app is receiving message in background but it is giving error on sending background message.

Permission in AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/\>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/\>
```

Method Channel for sending SMS

```
import android.telephony.SmsManager

val CHANNEL = "example.sms"

override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler {
call, result -\>
if(call.method == "sendsms") {
val phone = call.argument\<String\>("phone")
val msg = call.argument\<String\>("msg")
if (phone != null && msg != null) {
sendSms(phone, msg)
}
} else {
result.notImplemented()
}
}
}


private fun sendSms(phoneNumber: String, message: String) {

        try {
            val smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault()
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null)
    
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    
    }
```